# How to load an Area Chart when the x-axis is date?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-visualization

I want to build an area chart in Google spreadsheets using the Charts visualization service.

This is how my data looks like:

[image]

And the script:

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(range);
  var options = {
    title: 'Dados',
    hAxis: {title: 'Data',  titleTextStyle: {color: '#333'}}
  };
var chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
chart.draw(data, options);
```

Which doesn't return any chart!

This is the code to retrieve the range values:

```
var range=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('mySheet').getRange("A1:B10").getValues();`
```

If the 1st column data is replaced by strings, it works perfectly. So I guess the problem is related with the data type of the 1st column. I've checked the reference, and Date should be allowed: https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/areachart#Data_Format

Help anyone?

Comment: Can you provide more code to show exactly how you are getting the data range from the spreadsheet?

Comment: Yes, please see my edited question above

Comment: Can you provide more info on how you got this working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you getting an error such as `The script completed but the returned value is not a supported return type.`? If so, this is because even though the Google Charts API supports Date values, Date values can't be passed from Apps Script server side functions to client side functions. I used a map function to create a new 2D array that converts the Dates to strings before sending them to the client side and I was able to successfully create a chart:

```
var range = ...
return range.map(function (row) { return [row[0].toString(), row[1]]; } );
```

Comment: That's exactly the case